# spark - compare key with values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

i'm starting with spark, and i didn't understand some concepts yet.

I have a file with pairs of names like this:

```
foo bar
bar foo
```

But are the same relation between foo and bar. i'm trying to create a rdd with just one relation

```
foo bar
```

I create this code:

```
step1 = joined.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+';'+y).map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1].split(';'))).sortByKey(True).mapValues(lambda x: sorted(x)).collect()
```

to create the first output, and i think i need another reduceByKey to remove existing values for the previous iteration but i don't know how to do that.

Am I thinking correctly?

Comment: do you mean the second record in your file has to be removed because its value already exists as a key in the first record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something simple like:

```
>>> sc.parallelize(("foo bar", "bar foo")).map(lambda x: " ".join(sorted(x.split(" ")))).distinct().collect()
['bar foo']
```

Comment: thanks @santon! I create a function to parse the lines just you suggest.
#parse lines of file
def parseLine(line):
    #sort the link to avoid the problem
    n1,n2 = ' '.join(sorted(line.split('\t'))).split(' ')
    return (n1, n2)

Answer (score 1):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f    

rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([('foo', 'bar'), ('bar', 'foo'), ])
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema=['c1', 'c2'])
df = df.withColumn('c3', f.sort_array(f.array(df['c1'], df['c2'])))
df.show()

# output:
+---+---+----------+
| c1| c2|        c3|
+---+---+----------+
|foo|bar|[bar, foo]|
|bar|foo|[bar, foo]|
+---+---+----------+
```

Using DataFrame is much easier

Comment: thanks @zhangtong. I like your suggestion to. It's good to see other ways to do the same thing. Thanks again!